# Rails - Drop down menu to execute actions in the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, hyperlink

I'm not sure I phrased the question correctly, but how would I create a drop down menu with options to create a new entry on a certain model? Let's say for example I have User, Expense, and Budget, and on the main page I want the option to add a new user, new expense, or new budget by selecting that option from a drop down; instead of clicking a link that takes me to "new_user_path", "new_expense_path", or "new_budget_path".

Comment: I have been searching for hours, it appears javascript or jQuery might be the answer here, but I have no idea how to implement that. In case the question wasn't very clear, basically I want a drop down menu with choices such as "add new user", or "add new expense" and then for that selection to take me right to the add new user page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using jQuery, this is what I would do:
Have a hash defined something like:

```
@urls = {"Create New USer..." => new_user_url, "Create new expense", => new_expense_path}
```

Then in the view have:

```
select_tag :create-model, options_for_select(@urls)
```

Then in application.js or something like that

```
$('#create-model').change(function() {
  window.location = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
});
```

I haven't tried it but it should work without too much editing.

Comment: Thanks @Gwilym Kuiper, headed in the right direction. Here's what I have so far based on your code, please feel free to guide the rest. In my index page (for now) I have @urls = {"Create New Client" => new_client_url, "Create new Saving" => new_saving_url}  and then I have select_tag ':create-model', options_for_select(@urls), :onchange => 'this.form.submit()', and I put the jQuery in the application.js file like you said. The drop down shows up and looks fine, but no action. Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing a include_tag in my file to use the jquery, is that possible?

Comment: In the extract you've shown me, it says: select_tag ':create-model', it should be just: select_tag :create-model