# Devise + drop in signup menu in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm having some trouble thinking about how to approach this: I'm using devise for authentication and want to use jquery to insert a dropdown box from the nav as a sign in menu that can be accessed from any page.  Since the devise controller action is only linked to the `sessions/new` view and the nav is a partial, what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: Maybe something like this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602169/rails-drop-down-menu-to-execute-actions-in-the-controller

Comment: Ok got it working but the click listener is not working form the root path.  It works from all other pages, though.  Any ideas?

Comment: The root path takes users to "/users/sign_in" but this listener won't work from here.  I've tried redirecting the root to "/" but that's not a controller action so I hit errors